# Infimum plus constant

Tags: real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a subset of the real numbers and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Then it is claimed that $$\inf_{x\in A}(x+\lambda)=\inf_{x\in A}(x)+\lambda$$

So first of all is this true?
Secondly, I have looked at the proof of it here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infimum_Plus_Constant

and to me it seems like there would be an error in the proof:
To go from the formulation in terms of an infimum to a formulation in terms of a supremum they write:

$$\inf_{x\in T}(x+\xi)=-\sup_{x\in T}(-x+\xi)$$

But shouldnt it be $\inf_{x\in T}(x+\xi)=-\sup_{x\in T}(-x-\xi)$ (which of course would make the actual claim in the very first equation false)?

Comment: Assuming $\ \inf_{x\in A}(x)\ $ exists then of course it's true.

Comment: It is just a small typo. If you change $\xi$ to $-\xi$ at the first step the proof works fine.

Comment: "which of course would make the actual claim in the very first equation false?" No it wouldn't. Why do you think this?

Comment: @AdamRubinson because then you have $-\sup_{x\in T}(-x-\xi)=-\sup_{x\in T}(-x)-\xi=\inf_{x\in T}(x)-\xi$

Comment: You've made a mistake there: $\ -\sup_{x\in T}(-x-\varepsilon)= -\sup_{x\in T}(-x) -\sup_{x\in T}(-\varepsilon) = -\sup_{x\in T}(-x) +\sup_{x\in T}(\varepsilon) =-\sup_{x\in T}(-x) +\varepsilon.$

Comment: $-\sup_{x\in T}(-x-\xi)=-\Big(\sup_{x\in T}(-x)-\xi\Big)=\inf_{x\in T}(x)+\xi$

Comment: thanks to all of you